# Flutter ListView delete Items not working

Tags: list, flutter, listview

I have a ListView.builder with widgets and I would like to remove items from it but when I execute the Lines below nothing happens.

```
if (mounted) {
  setState(() {
    verlustContentList.removeLast();
  });
}
```

This is how I generate the List:

```
  generateList() async {

   return verlustContentList = List.generate(
     15,
     (index) => VerlustContent(
       key: Key(
         index.toString(),
       ),
       
     ),
   );
 }
```

This is how I display the List:

```
StreamBuilder(
                  stream: generateList().asStream(),
                  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: verlustContentList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        
                          return verlustContentList[index];
                        
                      },
                    );
                  },
                );
```

The Class VerlustContent is a Statefulwidget.

Comment: How are you invoking the setState?

Comment: In the onPress function of my Button I call  setState(() {
    verlustContentList.removeLast();
  });

Comment: try calling your removeLast function outside the set state and add setState((){}); after that ...

Comment: no that doesnt sovlve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StreamBuilder listens to a stream you defined but you never **push** new data to that stream.

If you would print the list after the .removeLast(), it would really print the list without the last one.

I think you should remove the StreamBuilder because you can't even access that stream this way. Generate the list on initState() and show it in ListView. If generation does take some time, you can return a CircularProgressIndicator() if list is empty.

```
class MyStateful extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyStatefulState createState() => _MyStatefulState();
}

class _MyStatefulState extends State<MyStateful> {
  List<Text> list= [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    generateList();
  }
  void generateList() {
   list = List.generate(
     15,
     (index) => Text(
       index.toString()
       
     ),
   );
 }
  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
      body: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                   Container(
                     height: 300,
                     child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: list.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                           return list[index];
                        },
                     ),
                   ),
                   ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                         if (mounted) {
                            setState(() {
                               list.removeLast();
                               print(list);
                            });
                         }
                      }, 
                      child: Text('deleteLast'),
                   ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
    );
  }
}
```